# laravel data foreach loop joiin

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have more than one category and inside these categories there is "pages". I want to change the name of this `pages` via foreach, but I couldn't merge it. how can i do it?

```
public function getCategory($lang): array
    {

        $data = [];
        $categories = Category::where('language', $lang)->with('pages')->get();

        foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
            $data[] = [
                'title' => $category['title'],
                'path' => $category['slug'],
            ];
            foreach ($category['pages'] as $keys => $page) {
                $data[] = [
                    'children' => [
                        'title' => $page['title'],
                        'path' => $page['slug']
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
        return $data;

    }
```

output

```
[
    {
        "title": "corporate",
        "path": "corporate"
    },
    {
        "children": {
            "title": "corporatealt",
            "path": "corporatealt"
        }
    },
    {
        "children": {
            "title": "corporatealt2",
            "path": "corporatealt2"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "blabla",
        "path": "blabla"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getCategory($lang): array
    {

        $data = [];
        $categories = Category::where('language', $lang)->with('pages')->get();

        foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
            $d = [
                'title' => $category['title'],
                'path' => $category['slug']
            ];
            if (!empty($category['pages'])) {
               $d['children'] = array_map(function($page){return [
                   'title' => $page['title'],
                    'path' => $page['slug']
               ];}, array_values($category['pages']));
            }
            $data[] = $d;
        }
        return $data;

    }
```

Comment: There is no point in writing children if pages are empty, how can I remove it?

Comment: Check if (!empty($category['pages'])) and then add children using second foreach. Will update answer when I am online

Comment: Updated answer to only include children if not empty and using array_map as more consice way